# Format negative values in reports

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a report which contains 10 columns of stock values.

When a stock value is negative I would like the text in my report to be formatted differently, for example I may wish to format it in Bold & Red.

Is this something I need to do in the `fetch` method?

At the moment my fetch method is very basic, just using `setRecord` once to setup a temporary table.

Is it possible and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the `tutorial_ColourLines` report.

```
reportSection.foregroundColor(colour);
```

The report changes the color of a report section, but it can be done to individual report controls as well.